# Not able to uploade website on server

Tags: asp.net

I am try to uploading website.I don't know how configure database(web.config file) on uploading time.I am using Somee.com , anyone familiar with somee.com Or know how to configure database the please help me.

**webconfig file code**

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="abc" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Jai-Ganesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\testinmg\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" ></customErrors>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Note: I don't know what is path of the dataSource in server.

Link of the page:
[**http://www.imureditor.somee.com/add_value.aspx**][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to contact your hosting provider for connection string. They will give you the ip address (you can also the host name) which you can then configure it.
See the exmaple below;

```
<add name="connectStringName" connectionString="Data Source=somee.com;User ID=yourusernameforDB;password=yourpasswordforDB;Initial Catalog=yourDBName;" />
```

OR take a real example below;

```
<add name="KenSchoolConnectionString" connectionString="Password=1234;Data Source=192.168.1.1;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=KenMISSchoolDB;User ID=sa" />
```

OR 
Go to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012#sqlconnection)

Comment: thnx Dotnetdreamer....  but have same issue they are provide  this connection string  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                        workstation id=testtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=vmagic089_SQLLogin_1;pwd=hmeq8v2nro;data source=testtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=testtest

Comment: thnx Mr.DotNet Dreamer for help.i solve out this problem.one more thing ,I have to know how can i upload my database to different server.

Comment: you have to backup your database first and then restore it. Or generated an sql file and execute it on the server. Or try youtube.com

Comment: Hello Mr.DotNet Dreamer.I am try to find free web hosting .I get domain name from .tk website.Now i am looking for free web hosting space.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string references your local SQL Server instance and tries to attach a local file; this connection string will need to be changed to reflect the setup on the server, so you'll need to specify the `Data Source`, `Catalog`, `User ID` and `Password` - `Integrated Security` won't work, and attaching *.mdf files from `App_Data` probably won't either.

Your service provider is responsible for giving you the credentials needed for this, we can't guess them.

Comment: 'workstation id=testtest.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=vmagic089_SQLLogin_1;pwd=hmeq8v2nro;data source=testtest.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=testtest'

Comment: this is conntection string they are provide ,but still not working :(